# R ggsurvplot fixing ratio

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Im at preparing the last plots for submission but cant get the last things correct. What i want to do is making the plot square and having the risk table follow it size.

I'm using this code
 `ggsurvplot(survfit(Surv(time,event) ~ "(hidden)"), risk.table = T, legend.labs = c("(hidden)","(hidden)"), pval = T, xlab = "Days", ylab= "Cum Survival", xlim = c(0,1000), break.x.by = c(200), surv.plot.height = 2,ggtheme = theme(aspect.ratio = 1))` for my survival plot. 
[image]

But what a get is a square plot but also a square risk table. Any ideas on how to make the code not apply to the risk table?

Sincerely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the awkward aspect ratio one can specify `tables.theme` in the call to `ggsurvplot`. Example:

```
library(survminer)
library(survival)

ggsurvplot(survfit(Surv(time, status)~ sex, data = lung), risk.table = T,
           legend.labs = c("M" ,"F"),
           pval = T,
           xlab = "Days",
           ylab= "Cum Survival",
           xlim = c(0,1000),
           break.x.by = c(200),
           surv.plot.height = 2,
           ggtheme = theme(aspect.ratio = 1),
           tables.theme =  theme(aspect.ratio = 0.2))
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to determine the best aspect.ratio for the table without test/error? Thanks.

Comment: @jgarces I think the ratio should be close to  `number of strata`/`(max(xlim)/break.x.by)`. For the above plot it would be 1/5 or 0.2 as I posted in the answer